# do general script for links with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script like:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $("a.link").on("click",function(){
         window.open('http://site.com/fir.php','_self',false);
     });
</script>
```

and I am using it as

```
<a  href="fir.php" class="link">
fir
</a>
```

How can I make only one script and pass as variable the url I want to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
 $("a.link").on("click",function(){
     window.open('http://site.com/'+$(this).attr('href'),'_self',false);
 });
 </script>
```

You can use **.prop** also like

```
window.open('http://site.com/'+$(this).prop('href'),'_self',false);
```

Comment: you should use prop() instead of attr()

Comment: Yah ofcourse @Stiger we can use it...Thanks for your suggestion..I will update my ans

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.href` to get the specific link's href to navigate to open in window but make sure to stop the link's default behavior with `.preventDefault()`:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $("a.link").on("click",function(e){
       e.preventDefault();// or return false; 
       window.open('http://site.com/'+this.href, '_self', false);
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this HTML code.May be it will helps you

```
 $(function(){
  $("a.link").on("click",function(e){
    window.open(this.href, '_self', false);
  });
 });
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is to avoid repeating the code for each link. How does this solve that?

Comment: $(function(){
    $("a.link").on("click",function(e){
       window.open(this.href, '_self', false);
    });
 });
 you can you this code then